# Can we set GEO filters for distance search using Yii2-Sphinx?

Tags: php, yii, yii2, sphinx

I am using Yii2-sphinx extension and everything working fine. Now I am doing distance search using sphinx so i want to set latitude and longitude for a given postcode. How can I set those two filters for my index?

As sphinx has an option to set geofilters but in yii2-sphinx, I am not able to do this.

Answer (score 0):

See, 
http://sphinxsearch.com/blog/2013/07/02/geo-distances-with-sphinx/

Want a query somewhat like

```
SELECT *, GEODIST(0.659298124, -2.136602399, latitude, longitude) as distance 
  FROM geodemo WHERE distance < 10000 ORDER BY distance ASC LIMIT 0,100;
```

So would need to use GEODIST function in `->select()` and the filter in `->andWhere()`

May want to change the order too.

Comment: Yes i am using almost same but not able to change these values 0.659298124, -2.136602399. These two values will be dynamic as values will be changed according to the given postcode. I am using join query and the query is written in sphinx.conf file as join is not supported in sphinx query builder.

Comment: Well they are just the lat/long expressed in radians, will need to look it up from the API. You need the lat/long attributes in radians in the sphinx index too. It can't go in teh sql_query, asi its dynamic. The location is dependn't on the specific query, can be hardcoded in the index.

Comment: can you please help me in building such query?